# Content box not responding to child Masonry content height. fiddle incl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

Right now I am struggling to get my #content div to respond to the height of my position: absolute articles. I have tried multiple methods but all failed. I know I need some JS to calc the height. I also made a fiddle, and as you can see the #content div doesnt react to the articles.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PCakirli/59zj721y/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">         
    <div id="content">
        <article></article>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
}                                                       

#content{
   max-width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
}

article{
   background: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   width: 32%;
}
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener("load", renderGrid, false); 
window.addEventListener("resize", renderGrid, false);

function renderGrid(){

var blocks = document.getElementById("content").children;
var pad = 20, cols = 3, newleft, newtop;
for(var i = 1; i < blocks.length; i++){
    if(i % cols == 0){
        newtop = (blocks[i-cols].offsetTop + blocks[i-cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
        blocks[i].style.top = newtop+"px";
    }else{
        if(blocks[i-cols]){ 
            newtop = (blocks[i-cols].offsetTop + blocks[i-cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
            blocks[i].style.top = newtop+"px";
        }
        newleft = (blocks[i-1].offsetLeft + blocks [i-1].offsetWidth) + pad;
        blocks[i].style.left = newleft+"px";
    }
}
}
```

I hope one of you can help me :)

Comment: What expected react to the #content div? I don't understand, everything is fine to me. I see a 3 x 3 grid. I put a content and stay correctly.

Comment: The height of my #content div shows a height of 0. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the height content div  is 0 :) And if you get the document height?

```
$(document).height();
```